# How can I construct a Django Template Tag condition statement to check the request method for POST?

Tags: django, django-templates

First, what I'd like to work:

```
{% if method == POST %}
    {% include "app/template_x.html"%}
{% else %}
    {% include "app/template_y.html"%}
{% endif %}
```

I'm using class based views, inheriting from django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView

I tried a few things, among them passing an HttpRespons.method object via extra context in the urls.py asview() function. 
Anyone have an idea how I should approach this problem?

Edit: Using request.method always returns "GET" upon template rendering. I want the user to be able to submit a form and have the template render a different {% include "template" %} on the same page following confirmation of success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% if request.method == "POST" %}
    {% include "app/template_x.html"%}
{% else %}
    {% include "app/template_y.html"%}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I tried this, request.method returned "GET" every time. I think its part of the template rendering order. When I submit my form entry, the page re-loads and the request.method prints "GET" {{request.method}}. I expected the "GET" to be "POST" after I submitted the form and the data was sent to the database.

Comment: because you do something like this is `views.py` not the template, `POST` requests are only done in forms and accesing a webpage is considered `GET`, you did the X Y problem right now, tell us what you want to do

Comment: I want to send data via a django {{form}} and have the page re-load with a different {% include "template" %}

Comment: so if i get you correctly, same url renders different templates

Comment: Yes. I have two versions of a Bootstrap Navwindow, and after a user successfully submits data, I want to load/render Navwindow x instead of Navwindow y.  I wanted to do this without creating a new template file, but I'm willing to consider it among other options

Comment: in context add `'post' : False` as default value, then check if post is true in template, if not then include what you want, else include the other one, if the request is post, do your calculations and and in view say `context['post'] = True`, now that should help you

Comment: I think I get it; so I add context['post'] = True to the "return" line on my "Success URL" function, and set the default through the extra context

Comment: You set it to false as default, and only make it true if the form is valid